# Search with Multiple parameters with dynamic values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am doing searching with 4 parameters with no mandatory fields
The Parameters are

1. City
2. Marital Status
3. Gender
4. Groups

As per the selection I am getting SQL queries like this

```
select * from UserTable 
where Gender='Male' AND City='' AND MaritalStatus='Single' AND Groups =''
```

It returns 0 rows as the parameters `City=''` AND `Groups =''` is not matching the criteria.

Is there any way to achieve this without going to check for null in multiple combinations.I am using `MSSQL2012` as my database and `Asp.Net C#`.

My method is as follows

```
private void GetSearchResults(string city, string MaritalStatus, string Gender, string Groups)
{
    var qry="select * from UserTable 
    where Gender='"+Gender+"' AND City='"+city+"' AND MaritalStatus='"+MaritalStatus+"' AND Groups ='"+Groups+"'";
}
```

What about my selection group='' Means I don't want any filtration on Group

Comment: I think some sample data would help in answering this and some expected outputs.  It is not 100% clear where you expect to find nulls, how you want to handle them and how you want the query to behave if a parameter has not been supplied.

Comment: Where, and how are you generating the query?

Comment: I have updated my questions

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from UserTable where Gender='Male' AND City IS NULL AND MaritalStatus='Single' AND Groups IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have below parameters

```
@Gender = 'Male',
@City = '',
@MaritalStatus = 'Married'
@Groups = ''
```

and your sql looks like.

```
select * from UserTable 
where 
(Gender = @Gender OR ISNULL (@Gender, '') = '')
AND (City = @City OR ISNULL (@City, '') = '')
AND (MaritalStatus = @MaritalStatus OR ISNULL (@MaritalStatus, '') = '')
AND (Groups = @Groups OR ISNULL (@Groups, '') = '')
```